# Send Google Analytics to two accounts

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I know there are many posts about this, but I can't find a solution that works for us.

We have an application that we track in Google analytics.

But each page should be able to send tracking data to two different Google Analytics accounts. And then we want our costumers to only have to feed their UA-code into the the admin of our page, and then our page will generate everything needed for them to track the page, as well as us. So this need to be an automated process, where we won't have to set anything up in our Analytics account for them to track the page in theirs. I hope that makes sense.

Just to illustrate, this is what we do now:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXX"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }

    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXX');
</script>
```

And this is what we tried. It seems to work, but could this solution cause any problems?

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXX"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }

    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXX');
    gtag('config', 'UA-YYYY');
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This set up won't cause any specific problems as long as you're not using any other custom tracking scripts aside from `gtag('config', ...)`.
Also, if your customers' pages reside on a specific subdomain you might be willing to add an additional parameter to their code:

```
gtag('config', 'UA-YYYY', {
  'cookie_domain': 'custom_subdomain.example.com'
});
```

This will provide a little bit more accurate distinction between new and returned users in customers' analytics reports.